# PHP List Explode Variable

Tags: php, list, variables, explode

Using PHP, I'm trying to give each specific text its own variable. I believe this can be achieved by using the explode list function in php. Something similar to the code below:

```
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = explode(":", $data);
```

However, the above code separates the text by using a colon (`:`). The text I'd like to separate are within quotes, for example `"WORD"`. The example text I'd like to separate is as below:

> "AULLAH1" "01/07/2010 15:28 " "55621454" "123456" "123456.00"

I'd like the text/numbers `AULLAH1`, `01/07/2010 15:28`, `55621454`, `123456`, `123456.00` to all have a specific PHP variable. If possible, I'd like the PHP explode feature to separate the content by a beginning quote (") and an ending quote (").

Comment: In the end result or in the incoming data?

Comment: (1) Do you have any control over how these files are created? (2) Have you considered using an actual database?

Comment: **Pekka**: Thank you for your response, I extremely appreciate it. I'd like it as an incoming data. Again, thank you for your response. :)

**quantumSoup**: Firstly, thank you for your response, I extremely appreciate them. ;) (1) It's only the one file, there are a lot of steps besides this. Finding away to give the following a variable is all I need at the moment. (2) I've been told that before, but unfortunately, I don't have the ability to do so. Thank you for your response. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
$s = '"AULLAH1" "01/07/2010 15:28 " "55621454" "123456" "123456.00"';
preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/', $s, $matches);
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = $matches[1];
```

The most simliar way would be to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) =
    preg_split('/"(?: ")?/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: @Timwi, It doesn't fail; assigning to `list` gives `NULL` to `$home` and `$shell` in this case.

Comment: @strager Was it supposed to fail? The OP doesn't mention that and it's consistent with his current solution.

Comment: Ah OK, you were responding to a now deleted comment.

Comment: Hi Artefacto, I extremely appreciate your response and I'm grateful for all the effort you've put into your reply. I've used the preg_match_all method and it seems to work more than perfectly. Also, I liked the idea of using preg_split too, as for now I'll stick to the first method. Again, I appreciate your response. Thank you for your help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the *simplest* solution, but certainly not the most *robust*:

```
$data = '"AULLAH1" "01/07/2010 15:28 " "55621454" "123456" "123456.00"';

list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell)
    = explode('" "', trim($data, '"'));

var_dump(array($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell));

// gives:
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "AULLAH1"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "01/07/2010 15:28 "
  [2]=>
  string(8) "55621454"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "123456.00"
  [5]=>
  NULL
  [6]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Hi Strager, I extremely appreciate your response as well as your efforts. In all honesty, I don't like the idea of going into arraying the data, although I do understand that it can be extremely useful at times. Sorry if I seem to be giving you a negative vibe, as stated before, I am grateful that you responded. ;) Thank you.

Comment: @AUl The arraying was just for displaying purposes.

Comment: @AUllah1, @Artefacto is correct; I just put the elements into an array to easily view the `var_dump` to show that it works as expected.

Comment: Ahh, that's great. Apologies for the assumption strager. That seems like some amazing coding. I appreciate your response. ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done with a regular expression. See the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) function for this.

Comment: This is low-quality and is better positioned as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
explode('-', str_replace('"', '', str_replace('" "', '"-"', $data)));
```

Comment: This will fail on `"01/07/2010 15:28 "`.

Comment: Hi Omar, thank you for your response. I extremely appreciate it. As mentioned by strager, it did fail at that specific location. :( Again, I really do appreciate your response as well as your effort. ;)